# find pid of ftp transfer in bash script

Tags: bash, ftp, solaris, pid

I would like to get the pid of an ftp inside a bash script... running on solaris

this is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
...
ftp -inv $FTPDEST <<EOF
user $USER $PASS
put $file
EOF
```

I would like to get the pid of the ftp command so that i can after check if it is hung and kill it.. 
I had a server crash because there were about 200 ftp process open when an ftp was cutting the connection.. for some reason the ftp process remained open.

thank you
Mario

Comment: If you want to kill every ftp process something like `pkill ftp` should be enough. But it is only an assumption, or do you want to kill the unique ftp process which your script launch?

Comment: I only want to kill the ftp process the script launch if at the end of the script it has not exited..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you seem to describe but may not really be what you need.  And this is a kind of hack....

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
trap 'exit 0' SIGUSR1   # this is the normal successful exit point

 # trigger the trap if ftp in a background process completes before 10 seconds    
(ftp -inv $FTPDEST <<-EOF 2>>logfile
user $USER $PASS
put $file
EOF 
kill -s SIGUSR1 $PPID ) &   # last line here shuts process down.  and exits with success

childpid=$!    # get the pid of the child running in background
sleep 10       # let it run 10 seconds

kill $childpid # kill off the ftp command, hope we get killed of first
wait
exit 1    # error exit ftp got hung up
```

Parent  waits for 10 seconds while the ftp child completes in less than 10 seconds for a successful exit.
Success mean the child send a SIGUSR1 signal to the parent which then exits via the trap.

If the child takes too long, the parent kills off the slow ftp child and exits with error.